# Command Line: removing text from echo data in a Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-arguments

In a batch file, I am trying to figure out how to remove characters at front/back of an command echo'd data.  Not specifically with a directory, but for sake of example.  Is there a way to strip characters at front or back of data as it is written to a file?

EXAMPLE:    `dir /b *.txt >dir.txt`

This result would save the filenames of a directory:
        filename.txt
        thisistest.txt
        hardquestion.txt

but I would like to strip out last 4 characters of the filenames so it would echo to *dir.txt* only the filename:
        filename
        thisistest
        hardquestion

Answer (score 2):

```
>dir.txt (for %%a in (*.txt) do echo %%~na)
```

`for` command will iterate over the indicated set of files and for each one, a reference to the file is stored in the replaceable parameter (`%%a` in this case) and the code after the `do` clause executed.

In this case, the code executed for each of the files is `echo %%~na`, echo the name of the file referenced by `%%a`

All the `for` command output is redirected to the final file.